# PrefixLM pretraining objective and PrefixLM-type architecture

Tags: huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

According to my understanding the pretraining objective is determined by the used  attention mask pattern as mentioned in [T5 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10683.pdf) figure3. Currently I am trying to grasp a new paper about pre-training objectives [UL2: Unifying Language Learning Paradigms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.05131.pdf)  In this paper the mentioned in page 13

> Within the context of decoder-only models, except for the case of the
> decoder model trained on causal LM, our experiments always use a
> bidirectional receptive field only in it’s input segment and
> autoregressive decoding at the targets segment. This is essentially
> the a PrefixLM-type architecture5 (Raffel et al., 2019) which we find
> to be consistently better than a full causal decoder model

then they note down

> ```
> Not to be confused with the PrefixLM pretraining objectiv
> ```

This refers to figure 4 in [Exploring the Limits of Transfer Learning with a Unified Text-to-Text Transformer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.10683.pdf) paper.

The question is:
There are three common structures for the transformer
encoder (use bidirectional mask for self attention)
decoder (use causal mask for self attention)
encoder-deoder transformer

In figure 4 the most left figure is for encoder decoder transformer, the middle one for language modeling structure which is decoder, what about the right figure? Is it a decoder that uses attention prefix_LM mask ? or what is the case here?

I am confused becase it is already mentioned down the figure 4 that

> Right: Adding a prefix to a language model corresponds to allowing fully-visible masking over the input

and this means that it is a decoder that uses prefix-LM mask pattern. If it is about using a mask so why calling it a structure and diffrentiate it from prefixLM pretraining objective?
.